# Gravar valores de array no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando, sem sucesso, gravar algumas informações em meu banco de dados, tenho uma tabela onde o usuário irá inserir linhas de acordo com a sua necessidade, mas ao enviar as informações para o banco está gravando somente a última informação.

O formulário da tabela é esse:

```html
        <form action="insertKit.php" method="post" target="_blank">
            <div class="table-responsive">
               <table id="products-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <th width="15%">Nº</th>
                        <th width="16%">Qtde.</th>
                        <th width="15%">Código</th>
                        <th width="32%">Descrição</th>
                        <th width="22%" class="actions">Ações</th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="numero[]" ></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantidade[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="codigo[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]"></td>
                        <td class="actions">
                           <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                           <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">Adicionar Linha</button>
                           <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Gravar</button>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tfoot>
               </table>
            </div>
         </form>
```

A página de inserção é essa:

```
for( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['numero']); $i++ ) {     

    // INSERINDO NO MYSQL
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query = "INSERT INTO kits  
                (numero,
                quantidade,
                codigo, 
                descricao   
                ) 
            VALUES 
                (
                '".$_POST['numero'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['quantidade'][$i]."',             
                '".$_POST['codigo'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['descricao'][$i]."' 
                )";

                echo $query;

}

    $queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die('ERRO ao inserir registro no Banco');

    if ( $queryExec) {
        echo "GRAVADO COM SUCESSO";     
    } else {        
        echo "ERRO NA GRAVAÇÃO DO KIT";
    }
```

Comment: Lembrando que as funções do tipo `mysql_` já foram descontinuadas no PHP 5.5, e não funcionam mais no PHP 7+
Sugiro que leia isso [Porque não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Olá @Knautiluz, valeu pela dica, esse é um sistema que estou refazendo e estava testando se tudo estava funcionando, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que está havendo um erro de posição nas linhas do script.

Não precisa colocar a string de conexão com o banco dentro do loop `for`, basta declarar ela uma só vez antes do `for`.

A linha de conexão `$queryExec` você pode colocar dentro do loop `for`, porque aí vai gravando cada informação no loop.

O código ficaria assim:

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);

for( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['numero']); $i++ ) {     

    // INSERINDO NO MYSQL
    $query = "INSERT INTO kits  
                (numero,
                quantidade,
                codigo, 
                descricao   
                ) 
            VALUES 
                (
                '".$_POST['numero'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['quantidade'][$i]."',             
                '".$_POST['codigo'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['descricao'][$i]."' 
                )";

                echo $query;

    $queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die('ERRO ao inserir registro no Banco');
}

    if ( $queryExec) {
        echo "GRAVADO COM SUCESSO";     
    } else {        
        echo "ERRO NA GRAVAÇÃO DO KIT";
    }
```

Comment: Olá @David Sam, obrigado por me fazer ver esse vacilo monstruoso.